# Azure pipeline - ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1029) Lost UI shared context

Tags: azure, integration-testing, azure-pipelines, revit-api

I have a pipeline on Azure that runs on a Windows 10 virtual machine that at some point calls a test task for an assembly (.dll) that tests functions for a Revit (3D modelling software) plugin.

In order to run the tests, the pipeline is simply running a command line task that starts RevitTestFramework, an open source application (https://github.com/DynamoDS/RevitTestFramework) used for this kind of testing.
Here are the relevant parts of my pipeline's yaml:

```
trigger:
  - develop

pool: 'Default'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
# Some steps here

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      cd %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\RevitTestFramework\bin\AnyCPU\Debug
      RevitTestFrameworkConsole.exe --dir %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\RevitTestFramework\bin\AnyCPU\Debug -a %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\RevitTestFramework\Tests\ModelEstablishment.IntegrationTests\bin\Debug\ModelEstablishment.IntegrationTests.dll -r %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\RevitTestFramework\Tests\results.xml -revit:"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2020\Revit.exe" --continuous
```

Where %ALLUSERSPROFILE% is C:\ProgramData, but I also tried different folders (including C:) with the same result.

The very last line is the one that causes the issue. If it is a bit confusing, it is just summoning the program `RevitTestFrameworkConsole.exe`,  which lives under the directory `--dir` and it has to test the assembly `-a`, spit out the results at `-r`, using the version of Revit specified at the path after `-revit`.

If I run this with my command line in Windows (not through the Azure pipeline) it runs perfectly:
[image]

But if it is Azure running it then it starts idling, repeating these lines until it cancels itself:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:8088/devtools/browser/fa35cb10-8f4d-468f-9b0e-6457845ff8b2
Running C:\RevitTestFramework\bin\AnyCPU\Debug\RTF_Batch_Test.txt
[1202/180047.796:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1029)] Lost UI shared context.
```

[image]

I've done my research but all I can find is that that error shouldn't be an actual error that breaks things and it usually happens when testing headless Chrome (which I'm far from doing).

Does anyone know what's going on here and how do I fix this?

**UPDATE**
By comparing the processes of manually running the command through the command line in the VM and what happens when Azure runs the same command, I've noticed that right after the line that says `Running C:\ProgramData\RevitTestFramework\bin\AnyCPU\Debug\RTF_Batch_Test.txt` (see screenshots) Revit is supposed to startup and run the tests. So I'm thinking that Azure's pipeline runs that command differently from what I do when I run the command on the same VM's command line.
Maybe this can help understanding the issue

Comment: is your VM restarted by any chance after completing?

Comment: @charithsuminda the VM is never restarted. Also there is no completion with this as it gets stuck repeating that error oven and over until it cancels itself

Comment: Can you check your self-hosted agent mode, service or interactive mode?  You could try to configre an agent with interactive process and auto-logon enabled. Then you could check if it could make some changes. Here is a doc about configure self-hosted agent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#choose-interactive-or-service-mode